# Chart.js -- using update() with time scale datasets

Tags: chart.js

Chart.js (v2.7.2) appears to render line chart axis labels dynamically for an axis that uses time scale. This creates a unique problem when using the `update()` method after updating your datasets.

`update()` starts a trace that ends in the `ChartElement.determineDataLimits` method:

```
// Convert labels to timestamps
for (i = 0, ilen = chart.data.labels.length; i < ilen; ++i) {
    labels.push(parse(chart.data.labels[i], me));
}
```

Because I have no `labels` element in my `data` -- each dataset has its own label, and the time scale labels are generated automatically -- the above code effectively prevents me from using `update()` on my time-scaled chart.

I have tried combinations of `destroy()`/`clear()` and `render()` to try to work around this problem, but that causes an even weirder exception in `Chart.transition`:

```
    transition: function(easingValue) {
        var me = this;

        for (var i = 0, ilen = (me.data.datasets || []).length; i < ilen; ++i) {
            if (me.isDatasetVisible(i)) {
                me.getDatasetMeta(i).controller.transition(easingValue);
            }
        }

        me.tooltip.transition(easingValue);
    },
```

Apparently, `me.getDatasetMeta(i).controller` is undefined.

What I am attempting to do is the following:

1) Render a time scale line chart similar to the official example here: http://www.chartjs.org/samples/latest/scales/time/line-point-data.html

2) Retrieve entirely new data sets via AJAX

3) Re-render the line chart.

It seems like the `new Chart(context, config)` constructor is the only way to actually render a time scale line chart.

My question has two parts:

A) Is this a bug, or am I doing something wrong?

B) Regardless of the answer to (A), is there any other way to do this without completely removing the chart and its data and rendering a band new chart in its place?

Comment: have you got a solution on this?

Comment: I did figure out how to make this work. I will dig up my solution (hopefully tonight) and post an answer to my own question.

Comment: I had a moment just now, so my solution is posted below.

Comment: perfect. thank you for the reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer: I saved the original chart as an object variable upon which I can call `destroy()`. After calling `destroy()`, I render a new chart to the same object variable.

The long answer (code samples, pulled from ES6 source):

```
updateTimeScaleChart() {
    this.timeScaleChart.destroy()
    this.drawTimeScaleChart()
},

drawTimeScaleChart() {
    this.timeScaleChart = new Chart($('#timeScaleChart'), {
        type: 'line',
        data: this.prepareTimeScaleChartData(),
        options: {
            aspectRatio: 1.25,
            title: {
                display: true,
                text: 'Measured over Time'
            },
            scales: {
                xAxes: [{
                    type: 'time',
                    scaleLabel: {
                        display: true,
                        labelString: 'Date'
                    }
                }]
            }
        }
    });
},
```

`this.drawTimeScaleChart()` is called when the my component is initially rendered with blank data while it waits for the JSON API data to be retrieved.

`this.prepareTimeScaleChartData()` is a method that formats my JSON API response into the expected ChartJS data structure.

From there, it's just a matter of triggering `updateTimeScaleChart()` for appropriate events.

Comment: So essentially you destroy the whole thing, instead of updating the dataset..?

Comment: Yes. It works for my situation, so I stopped there. I have not tinkered with how it looks since it happens "below the fold" from my action trigger.

Comment: If you want to skip the redraw, i actually got an answer on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53400538/updating-chart-js-chart-with-dataset-of-different-size where the redraw works. just FYI

Comment: That's an interesting solution. I don't know if it would apply to my specific use-case. I will keep in mind if I run into a similar issue in the future.